# Local Webpage on iPad with Javascript

Tags: ios, ipad, local-storage

I have a simple web page with a javascript touch enabled slider that I would like my client to be able to run on their iPad without an internet connection.

Saving it to reading list kind of breaks the javascript.

If it's open with a connection and then exited, then reopened without a connection safari says it can't be opened but pushing the back button loads the cached version properly.

Is there a way to open cached files or save html files locally better?

Comment: Save it to your homescreen, for starters. There are other things you can do for caching, such as localStorage and such.

Comment: Sorry, I should've said that I did this, it achieves the same result as opening it online, disconnecting then reopening it. An error message from safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for two features that have been introduced with HTML5:

- [Offline web applications](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html) to make your page accessible even without an Internet connection
- [Local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) to save your page's data on the client